# jquery datepicker animation options wont work

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a textbox which has JQuery UI DatePicker control registered to it. It works fine but when I try to add animation options, control itself wont work.

```
<head runat="server">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#TextBox1").datepicker("option", "showAnim", 'slideDown');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Without the options, the picker would at least show itself. Can someone tell me a solution and better, what's happening? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

define options after init:

```
// initialization (~= constructor)
$("#TextBox1").datepicker();
// set options
$("#TextBox1").datepicker("option", "showAnim", 'slideDown');
```

or at the same time:

```
// initialization + options (~= constructor with args)
$("#TextBox1").datepicker({showAnim: 'slideDown'});
```

to resize it add this style to your html file after the `<link>` to jquery.ui.all.css (or in your custom .css):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.ui-datepicker{
     font-size:...px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Wow man! You seem to be jquery guru. Thanks a lot! BTW, how do I know I should do the binding twice, once normally, second time with the options? That thought would have never striked me

Comment: Is there any way to get down the datepicker's size?