# jQuery Datepicker showAnim not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, coffeescript

I've tried numerous ways and scoured the internet to try and make Animations work and have drawn a blank. I have the datepicker working and date format option but not animations (I'm looking to use the 'clip' option).

Here's what's in the various files:

Application.js

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Events.js.coffee

```js
jQuery ->
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
  );
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :image, as: :file, label: 'Image' %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Title' %>
<%= f.input :location, label: 'Location' %>
<%= f.text_field :date, id: 'datepicker', label: 'Date' %>
<%= f.input :time, label: 'Time' %>
<%= f.input :description, label: 'Description' %>
<%= f.input :organised_by, label: 'Organised by' %>
<%= f.input :organiser_description, label: 'Organiser description' %>
<%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Organiser site" %>

<%= f.button :submit, label: 'Submit' %>
```

Application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 */

@import 'normalize';
@import 'global.css.scss';
@import 'events.css.scss';
@import 'welcome.css.scss';
```

I've tried the following variations:

```coffee
$ ->
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy");
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");
  });
```

What am I missing? It's such a minor issue in the grand scheme of what I'm building, but I won't move on until this is fixed. All assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker animation options wont work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427539/jquery-datepicker-animation-options-wont-work)

Comment: maybe you need to change `Clip` to `clip` see here http://api.jqueryui.com/clip-effect/

Comment: Hi, no this doesn't work.

Comment: (1) Clean up your whitespace and indentation, you need to be consistent or your code won't be structured the way you think it is. (2) `Events.coffee` isn't CoffeeScript, that looks like a mix of JavaScript and CoffeeScript.

Comment: I've always labelled my files that way (events.js.coffee) - is that incorrect? I've come back to this today and I'm still struggling with it. I understand what you mean about whitespace but why would the dateformat work fine but not showAnim? Any other advice would be appreciated.